# Python selection-sort with while loop returns unaltered array—why?

Tags: python, algorithm, debugging, selection-sort

I hate having to ask like this, but I'm at my wits' end. Doesn't help that the assignment I'm doing this for requires a **while** loop contained in a **for** loop, rather than a nested **for** loop that every example I've ever been able to find has used. Very frustrating.

So here's the code, with comments written out for my own reference as best as I can understand what's going on (I'm not a very good programmer as of now).

```
def selection_sort(arr): 
    for indexvalue in range (0, len(arr) - 1): #we want to start with the 0th item in the index for selection sort and end at the second-to-last one, 
        currentmin = indexvalue #establishes the first variable as our lowest looked at so far. This is something that changes every time we go over the array, looking for the next lowest number 
        while indexvalue<len(arr): 
            if arr[indexvalue] < arr[currentmin]: #allows us to find the new lowest value—anything lower than our currently-located minimum should count as our new lowest value
                arr[indexvalue], arr[currentmin] = arr[currentmin], arr[indexvalue] #exchanges the two values so that our current lowest value is set one to the left in the array, and the new lowest value one to the right
                indexvalue = indexvalue+1 #adds another 1 to our counter so that we can compare the next-indexed items 
            else: #should occur when we reach the end of our array 
                break #forcibly ends the while loop, and by extension the function
```

Not really sure what's going on—as best as *I* can process it works, but it clearly doesn't. For example, when I run:

```
testlist=[10, 12, 15, 1, 0, 4, 99]
selection_sort(testlist)
print(testlist)
```

I get testlist, unaltered. Any idea why this might be? I'm clearly missing something important, but I have no clue what it might be.

Edit: new, improved code below. Not perfect, but it's sorting *something* now at least. This set results in a set of data that seems to be replacing elements with their index positions; I'm fairly sure that it's being caused by line 6. Not sure why though.

```
def selection_sort(arr): 
    for indexvalue in range (0, len(arr) - 1): #we want to start with the 0th item in the index for selection sort and end at the second-to-last one, 
        currentmin = indexvalue #establishes the first variable as our lowest looked at so far. This is something that changes every time we go over the array, looking for the next lowest number 
        while indexvalue<len(arr): 
            if arr[indexvalue] > currentmin: #allows us to find the new lowest value—anything lower than our currently-located minimum should count as our new lowest value
                arr[indexvalue], currentmin = currentmin, arr[indexvalue] #exchanges the two values so that our current lowest value is set one to the left in the array, and the new lowest value one to the right
                indexvalue = indexvalue+1 #adds another 1 to our counter so that we can compare the next-indexed items 
                print (arr)
            else: #should occur when we reach the end of our array 
                break #forcibly ends the while loop, and by extension the function
```

Comment: Your while loop terminates in the first iteration since `10 < 10 -> False -> break`

Comment: Oh, OK. That makes sense to me. So that part is a stupid oversight on my part. Any suggestions on fixing it?

Comment: To fix it, start by having it print a message every time it swaps a pair of numbers. Or learn how to use a debugger, and single-step your code. Then you'll be able to observe it and you'll figure out what to do.

Comment: That was a good idea. I got:[0, 12, 15, 1, 0, 4, 99]
[0, 10, 15, 1, 0, 4, 99]
[0, 10, 12, 1, 0, 4, 99]
[0, 1, 12, 1, 0, 4, 99]
[0, 1, 10, 1, 0, 4, 99]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 99]

[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 99] 

So  I think that it's replacing some of the numbers that it's trying to sort with their index positions. That's an odd one. I'll update my current code and leave it open to advice

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your while-loop you always compare `arr[currentmin]` with itself, because `currentmin == indexvalue` at the time. Since a value is never smaller than itself, the `else` branch takes over and ends the while-loop before any changes to the list could have been made.
This happens every iteration of the for-loop, thus leaving you with an unaltered list.

Possible solutions incoming!

> Either, you go with `if arr[indexvalue] <= arr[currentmin]:` in line 5, which is totally fine, since selection sort is not necessarily a stable sorting algorithm

or

> You add a line like `indexvalue = indexvalue + 1` before
> `if arr[indexvalue] < arr[currentmin]:`

Hope it helps (and I didn't overdo it with all the formatting ^^' )

### Continuation:

Now that we've got that out of our way, we should have a look at what happens within the if-statement:

When an element is found which is smaller than the yet smallest element, selection sort merely remembers this new index.
`currentmin = indexvalue`
There should be no swapping going on yet.
When `indexvalue` has reached the end of the list, `currentmin` should be pointing to the smallest not yet sorted element.

This smallest element is *now* supposed to be swapped with the first unsorted element which should be at `arr[indexvalue]`. But since you have used `indexvalue` to move over the rest of the list, the program does not know where the unsorted elements start. You'll need to define another "running-index" for use within the while-loop, initialized with `indexvalue` before the head of the while-loop.

Comment: This was supposed to help with the first version of your code.

Comment: I went back to the first version of the code, and while your answer makes sense (thanks!), neither of the solutions you proposed worked, sad to say.


The first only worked on the last two elements, and the second had no effect at all.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I completely messed up the selection sort algorithm.  While the basic idea your code implies is correct, you don't actually swap the elements as soon as you find a smaller one. Instead swapping is only supposed to happen, when `indexvalue` reached the end of the list. Editing now.

Comment: In response to the edited version: That makes some sense, and I recently came to the realization that I completely misunderstood how selection sort works. So my question now is...how do I do what you're recommending?

Comment: Well... I'm trying not to provide you with the solution directly, in order to maximize your learning-effect. Besides, I'm not that good with Python only enabling me to explain the algorithm itself. So let me start with a few steps to build up momentum towards the solution: First it is mandatory that you add the secondary running-index before entering the while-loop and change the while-loops condition accordingly. Next: do not swap within the while-loop, instead just update `currentmin`. Swapping should happen after the while-loop ended, but before the next for-iteration starts.

Comment: That'll help a bit! I'll get back to you. But to be honest I've found I learn coding best by being able to adapt and play with a functional example, though I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: I'm living in Germany and it's about 01:00 here now. I'll post a new answer with a solution I scraped together from the little Python I remember - last contact is years ago - and the code you already provided. Since I do not have a compiler at hand I can't promise that there are no syntax errors, but the semantics should be correct this time.

Comment: You don't have to do that, don't worry! I ended up calling my dad and after many, many hours of work we managed to figure it out. Thank you, thank you, thank you for being willing to help, though. I wish you all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you could learn best from fiddling around with working examples:
Enjoy and learn! ;)

```
def selection_sort(arr): 
    for indexvalue in range (0, len(arr) - 1): #we want to start with the 0th item in the index for selection sort and end at the second-to-last one, 
        indexval2 = indexvalue + 1 #new running-index in order not to lose track of where the unsorted part starts
        currentmin = indexvalue #establishes the first variable as our lowest looked at so far. This is something that changes every time we go over the array, looking for the next lowest number 
        while indexval2 < len(arr): 
            if arr[indexval2] < arr[currentmin]: #allows us to find the new lowest value—anything lower than our currently-located minimum should count as our new lowest value
                currentmin = indexval2 #sets currentmin to the new lowest value
            indexval2 = indexval2 + 1 #adds another 1 to our counter so that we can compare the next-indexed items
        arr[currentmin], arr[indexvalue] = arr[indexvalue], arr[currentmin] #swapping lowest to beginning of unsorted elements. This way it will be neglegted in the next for-iteration
```